# How to remain the textfield to 0? Clearing up the textfield will cause another value to isNaN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

If I leave this as a blank field, this will cause the  `total`  to display as  `isNaN` and I don't want the form to be submitted if it is an `isNaN`. How do I prevent the form from being submitted if the  `total` value shows as  `isNaN`?

```
export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [fee, setFee] = useState(0);
  const amount = parseInt(1000);
  const total = Number(amount) + Number(fee);
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(" submit");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={{ handleSubmit }}>
      <TextField
        label="Fee"
        type="number"
        value={fee}
        onChange={(e) => setFee(parseInt(e.target.value))}
        InputProps={{
          inputProps: {
            min: 0
          }
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <br />
      Total: {total}
    </form>
  );
}
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-7sfdph?file=/demo.js:171-809

Comment: You can use `setFee(parseInt(e.target.value || "0"))`

Comment: I would solve this by decoupling the fee (an integer) from the value of the text field (a state string). Implement a regular textfield with an initial state value of "". Then add a useEffect() that parses the value into the fee and calculates the total. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-3yv8gw?file=/demo.js)

Comment: @ChrisG But it accepts the negative value if I enter it in the input field

Comment: You can extend the `onChange` handler so it only allows certain values, like with any controlled input. However you're potentially frustrating the user because typing something has no effect rather than simply showing that the current value is invalid (which is my preferred way) (also note that your question is about preventing submission, which is a separate question altogether; please focus on one problem at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 onChange={(e) => {
          if(e.target.value===""){
            setFee(0);
          }else{
          setFee(parseInt(e.target.value))}}
        }
```

Comment: But this would not allow me to delete the 0 right? I would have to put a value before the 0 before I can delete it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [fee, setFee] = useState(0);
  const amount = parseInt(1000);
  const total = Number(amount) + Number(fee);

  // async is not required if you are not using await keywork in function.
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (isNaN(fee)) {
      console.log("its not a number");
    } else {
      console.log("its a number");
      
      // this submit will refresh page.
      // e.target.submit();


      // if you do not want page to refresh.
      // remeber there is different approch for image data.
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('fee', fee);
      console.log(formData);
      // continue with sending data to your backend server
    }
  };

  const changeFee = (e) => {
    setFee(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    // use only one curly braces
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <TextField
        label="Fee"
        type="text"
        value={fee}
        onChange={changeFee}
        InputProps={{
          inputProps: {
            min: 0
          }
        }}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      <br />
      Total: {total}
    </form>
  );
}
```

read the all comments mentioned in above code maybe it helps.